# Gnome Files showing files as folders in a samba share in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, samba, 20.04

After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 I couldn't connect to the samba share.

I managed to fix it by adding,
client min protocol = NT1

into,
/etc/samba/smb.conf

However now all the files are shown as folder in Gnome Files.

Please help.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. @Nmath if you browse to the share with Nautilus, it shows the Folder icon for files, and also treats them that way when sorting. If you try to open the files it tries to open a folder instead (it shows a deeper level in the treeview) and pops the error "This location could not be displayed: <filename> could not be found. Perhaps it has recently been deleted". This happens for all files. 
From what I read elsewhere on AskUbuntu, it might be a bug in samba.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's a confirmed bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1872476

It's already been fixed, but is not included in the current stable release yet. I you want to apply the patches yourself in the meantime, you can find them here:

https://gitlab.com/samba-team/devel/samba/-/commit/a33656c9df2cde3ff1cfc6b0427c7dfb2b140cae

https://gitlab.com/samba-team/devel/samba/-/commit/a95a8c7eaa46d5c8c485de714f0a97e307e49f7e

https://gitlab.com/samba-team/devel/samba/-/commit/39c910fd9cba3caf7414274b678b9eee33d7e20b

Comment: thanks ! Note: In the first link, the bug author provides a ppa and the steps for a fix without having to apply patches manually. Did it and it works now

Answer (score 0):

I had to start by installing Samba. I used this tutorial: [click here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-samba#4-setting-up-user-accounts-and-connecting-to-share)

Then I had to add this line "client min protocol = CORE"

to the [global] section of my /etc/samba/smb.conf file. I fount that direction [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/djvpdn/smb_connection_nautilus_error_debian_bullseye/)

I hope that helps.